# How to use download a PDF and convert it into a txt file in node.js? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, text, pdftotext

I am trying to get a pdf file by requesting a download link to download the file and then convert the text in it into a txt file. However, I am getting this error:

"(while reading XRef): Error: Invalid XRef stream
XRefParseException"

when loading the pdf into the parser. This sets off the error handler which just prints the error message.  Here is my code right now:

```
import request from 'superagent';
import PDFparser from 'pdf2json';

//a download link (indicated by the dl=1) for some dropbox example.pdf
link = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/22nvxasry8zpwbg/example%20(3).pdf?dl=1';  

//sending a request to this download link
request.get(link).end((err, res) => {
    if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/pdf') {
      //creates a new file and pipes the response into the stream
      let pdfId = 'search-' + Date.now();
      let file = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/pdf/' + pdfId + '.pdf');
      res.pipe(file);

      //api for pdfParser setting handlers
      pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => {
        console.error(errData.parserError) 
      });
      pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
        console.log('got data, writing to txt file');
        console.log("./tmp/txt/" + pdfId + ".txt");
        fs.writeFile("./tmp/txt/" + pdfId + ".txt", pdfParser.getRawTextContent());
      });

      //load the pdf file into the pdfParser
      // I think the error happens here
      pdfParser.loadPDF('./tmp/pdf/' + pdfId + '.pdf');

    }
});
```

I think the error happens when I'm trying to load the pdf into the parser, but I'm not 100% sure. And I don't know what to do about this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the api guide for superagent:
https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/

and the api guide for pdf2json: https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json

Comment: AHHHH... Is there any other way to get the content besides a PDF? Is there not a API your can access or could you scrape the page for content instead? (Trying to scrape a PDF sounds difficult from my experience just trying to create them)

Comment: I mean I'm just trying to account for all kinds of files. I started with txt files which were easy, but now I want to do .pdf and .doc (word) files. I'm stuck on pdf right now though

Comment: Did you try with one PDF (or with a set of PDFs from a single source) only, or does it fail on *any* random file?

Comment: PDFs are a pain to work with. As I mentioned, depending what you are actually trying to do you may be able to look at the network tab when downloading a PDF and see if it is hitting an API that you can hit directly instead of trying to pull the data out of the actual PDF